# Why is not "Je t'aime", "Je aime te"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, verbes, ordre-des-mots

If the following sentence is correct:

> J'aime le sandwich (I + like + the sandwich)

I expect (I + love + you) to be:

> J'aime te

Then, why is it "Je t'aime"?

Comment: `J'aime toi` is probably better than `J'aime te` but still not correct.

Comment: @iKiWiXz J'aime toi is not correct because toi cannot stand as a direct objet here. It "sounds" better to you probably because as a tonic pronoun it's its grammatical place to follow the verb.

Comment: This goes without saying (based on the way that you asked your good question), but if you had instead asked: “Why does « le sandwich » come after the verb whereas « t’/te » comes before the verb,” the answers probably would have included, in addition to the excellent explanations below concerning the positioning of object PRONOUNS (« t’/te » in this case) before the verb in French (unlike in English), an explanation that object NOUNS (« le sandwich » in this case) come after the verb in French (just as in English).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 rules that answer your question.

**First**: subject (direct or indirect one when complement to the verb) ending with 'e' and placed in front of a verb starting with a vowel must be shortened.
Thus, 'je', 'me', 'te' and 'se' will become " *j'* ", " *m'* ", " *t'* " and " *s'* " when in front of verb starting with a vowel.
"Je aime le chocolat" is incorrect => "*J'* aime le chocolat".
"Tu me as fais peur" is incorrect => "Tu *m'* a fais peur".

**Second**: when you shorten a direct complement of a verb, you must replace it with an indirect complement placed just in front of this verb.
"J'aime *le chocolat*" => "je *l'* aime".
So, "J'aime *toi*" (which is a form that no one will ever used because it sounds ugly) becomes "Je *t'* aime".

Answer (score 14):

The simple answer is "because it is the rule".

The rule says that object pronouns are always placed before the verb except in imperative affirmative sentences.

J'aime la France. → Je l'aime.
J'entends les oiseaux. → Je les entends.

An easy lesson on the subject on *[Bonjour de France](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/10/grammaire/166.html)*.