# Régime conjoint et disjoint des pronoms personnels: en quoi l'histoire contredit-elle la situation actuelle?

Tags: prononciation, pronoms-personnels, évolution

Après avoir lu une [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12724) sur le *pronom personnel* (te) et sa position dans la phrase, j'ai vu la règle au [*Grevisse*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) (a. 682) avec le titre: *Place du pronom **conjoint** autre que le sujet*. Dans les critères de variation de formes des pronoms personnels (a. 657), on donne l'exemple « *Je l'ai vu* » par opposition à « *C'est moi qui l'ai vu* » à titre d'illustration des formes de régime (conjoint et disjoint). Puis, il y a cette explication sur les deux formes:

> *Conjointes*, c'est-à-dire jointes directement au verbe. *Disjointes*, c'est-à-dire séparées du verbe. On les appelle aussi, respectivement,
>   *atones* et *toniques* ; mais cette notion fait appel à l'histoire, laquelle contredit partiellement la situation actuelle: dans
>   *Prends-le*, le est tonique, alors qu'historiquement, c'est une forme atone. Aujourd'hui, *je*, *me*, *te*, *se* sont toujours atones ; les
>   autres sont atones ou toniques (*moi*, *toi*, *soi*, *eux*, ne sont
>   atones que lorsqu'ils perdent leur accent au profit d'un monosyllabe
>   qui le suit: *moi seul*, *eux deux*, etc.).
>
> <sub>GREVISSE (Maurice) et GOOSSE (André), *le Bon Usage* — *Grammaire, langue française*, DeBoeck -Duculot</sub>

Qu'est-ce que cette explication ? Est-ce que ça sous-entend qu'auparavant une prononciation différente faisait en sorte que la position du pronom était différente ?

Je demande parce que dans le cas de l'impératif, l'auteur revient d'abord au présent... « *tu te lèves* » ; puis il indique qu'avec l'impératif, on doit substituer le pronom conjoint (*te*) par le pronom disjoint (toi), et ajouter le trait d'union... « *lève-toi* ».

Les deux régimes (et donc la position des pronoms) sont-ils fondés sur la prononciation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonétiquement, le `e` de *te* peut être muet, il perd ainsi toute tonicité :

> Tu t'lèves !

Mais si l'on veut insister on met la tonique sur le *te*, phonétiquement :

> Tu teu lèv' !

L'élision n'est pas possible pour *toi*.

Si l'on remplace *conjointes* par ce qui concerne le sujet du verbe, et *disjointe* par ce qui concerne l'objet du verbe :

En situation conjointe il y une forme de tautologie, de bégaiement : *tu te* concerne la même personne, on met la tonique sur le *tu*, car c'est à lui que la phrase est adressée, c'est donc lui qui va agir comme acteur principal.

En situation disjointe, *[tu] lèves toi* la tonique est sur le *toi*, car c'est toujours à lui que l'ordre est destiné.

Comment: Merci! J'en déduis que la forme conjointe est plus malléable phonétiquement que la forme disjointe. Indirectement je me demnade justement si c'est à dessein que _te_ est ainsi conjoint.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Lorsqu'un étranger dit *Je toi aimer*, il parle aussi comme un tout petit enfant, car l'usage veux un *te*, alors que logiquement l'expression de la pensée est valide avec *toi*, pour la retrouver on peut très bien dire *Je tttt'aime* en mettant une double tonicité sur le `t` pour manifester sa flamme à l'être aimé ; on retrouve ainsi l'expression singulière (unique, personnelle, valable dans l'instant présent) d'une émotion cordiale... ce qui est une part de la Vie que la grammaire ne peut border

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que ce que Grevisse veut dire, c'est que l'accent tonique s'est déplacé dans le cas de syntagme comme *prends-le*. En effet, l'accent tonique se mets en français moderne sur a dernière syllabe d'un syntagme (ici, *le*). À quelques exceptions près, ce mot n'est jamais un pronom atone.

J'imagine que Grevisse sous-entend qu'historiquement, dans *prends-le*, *le* ne portait pas l'accent tonique soit parce cet accent était à un autre endroit (Dans la plupart des langues romanes, il est sur l'avant-dernière syllabes), soit parce que l'expression était construite de telle manière que *le* (s'il était présent), ne prenait pas l'accent tonique.