# « Je, singulièrement animé à chérir ce qui, aimable, n'est pas aimé, entre toutes saisons le plus aime l'hiver » : le pronom conjoint isolé ?

Tags: grammaire, histoire, pronoms-personnels

> *Je*, singulièrement animé à chérir ce qui, aimable, n'est pas aimé,
>   entre toutes saisons le plus *aime* l'hiver, et poursuivre ce sens de la
>   pâleur Trophonienne sur sa face. [...]
>
> [ *I, singularly moved / To love the lovely that are not beloved, / Of all the Seasons, most / Love Winter and to trace / The sense of the Trophonian pallor on her face.* [...] ]
>
> [ Extrait de *L'Hiver*, d'une traduction de Paul Claudel publiée en
>   1911 dans la [*Nouvelle revue française*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Po%C3%A8mes_(Patmore)), d'un poème de Coventry
>   Patmore, [*Winter*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aF8LAAAAIAAJ&dq=patmore%20poems%20winter&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q=patmore%20poems%20winter&f=false) ]

---

Le bon usage (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> ed.) relate la surprise des lecteurs lors de la publication, de voir le pronom conjoint [isolé](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12743/3177) du verbe, peut-on s'imaginer. Et Paul Claudel dans une [lettre](https://books.google.com/books?id=awuLPX-D5cUC&lpg=PA46&dq=%22ce%20je%20suspendu%22&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q=%22ce%20je%20suspendu%22&f=false) à André Gide de rappeler le « Je qui chantai jadis » de [Scarron](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cz6IuQh01N8C&dq=%22je%20qui%20chantai%22%20scarron&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22je%20qui%20chantai%22%20scarron&f=false) et le « *je [soussigné](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/soussign%C3%A9/1)*, [nom propre], [verbe]... » ([Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/soussign%C3%A9_soussign%C3%A9e/73929/difficulte)), puis d'ajouter : « Que les gens sont bêtes ! ». Mais le sont-ils ? Dans ce dernier cas, le verbe *soussigner* était employé de manière pronominale au 16-17<sup>e</sup> ; voir au [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/239670) (on marque par *v. r.*, 14<sup>e</sup> l.) ; et au [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/soussigner), pour *signer* de manière réflexive : « Quand il escrivoit aux Grecs, il se soubsignoit Lucius Cornelius Epaphroditus », Amyot), et on nous dit que c'est la raison pour laquelle on a *soussigné* dans *je soussigné* ; une syntaxe archaïque. (*LBU14* §924 H1 où on réfère au FEW).

On ajoute (*LBU14* §667) qu'au Moyen-âge, le pronom sujet était souvent tonique, incluant je/tu/il, de sorte qu'il pouvait être séparé du verbe alors qu'on utiliserait aujourd'hui les formes disjointes (*moi* etc.) ; mais ça autorisait : « Et tu, Echo, qui faiz l'air resonner » ([Lemaire de Belges](https://books.google.com/books?id=-5pHAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22Et%20tu%2C%20Echo%2C%20qui%20faiz%20l'air%20resonner%22%20lemaire%20de%20belges&pg=PA172#v=onepage&q=%22Et%20tu,%20Echo,%20qui%20faiz%20l'air%20resonner%22%20lemaire%20de%20belges&f=false)), plutôt joli (mon avis). Curiosité régionale (Québec), dans des formules de style rattachées aux [serments](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_serments) qu'on prête, on a réussi à détacher le pronom conjoint, mais on est loin de la coupe aux lèvres...

---

- Pourquoi trouve-t-on juste/plus ou moins juste la comparaison que Paul Claudel fait entre sa traduction et les deux exemples *je qui chantai jadis*/*je soussigné* ?
- En regardant le texte que l'auteur traduisait on comprend probablement son choix, mais si on utilisait le pronom conjoint aujourd'hui comme il le faisait il y a un siècle, qu'est-ce que cet emploi ajouterait au registre/ton/style de la phrase (par exemple si on comparait avec la forme disjointe, est-ce identique, et on viserait quoi avec le procédé) ?

Comment: I don't like his translation at all. Chérir is to cherish. singularly moved to cherish what is unloved yet capable of being loved

Comment: Bon, soyons clairs. Pourquoi avoir mis l'anglais alors? Faut pas tout mélanger. Si je vois une mauvaise traduction, je peux le signaler, non? Vous faites comme bon vous semble et je ferais comme bien me semble. Après tout, il n'était pas traducteur. Et arrêtez un peu de me faire la morale....Personne a critiqué son FRANÇAIS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Pour référence

L’original anglais :

> I, singularly moved
>   To love the lovely that are not beloved,
>   Of all the Seasons, most
>   Love Winter, and to trace
>   The sense of the Trophonian pallor on her face.

La traduction de Claudel :

> Je, singulièrement animé
>   à chérir ce qui, aimable, n’est pas aimé,
>   entre toutes saisons le plus
>   aime l’hiver, et poursuivre
>   ce sens de la pâleur Trophonienne sur sa face.

---

#### Le choix de traduction : sourcier et/ou archaïsant ?

Claudel a décidé de transférer en français le pronom isolé qui débute le poème, construction envisageable et correcte (quoique rare) en anglais, mais se rattachant clairement à une version plus ancienne du français. Compte tenu de l’original, et si l’on désire une traduction à tendance [*sourcière*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traduction#%C3%89coles_de_pens%C3%A9e), comme c’est peut-être le cas ici, on peut certes accorder cette fantaisie au traducteur. Mais le monde littéraire semble avoir frémi à ce ***Je***. Est-ce parce que la tournure est vraiment par trop vieillie, peut-être devenue incompréhensible, ou simplement perçue comme de la plus haute inélégance ?

Le tour est vieilli, cela au moins n’est pas controversé, et il l’était déjà au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, avant l’époque de Claudel. Le fait qu’il cite *« **Je qui chantai jadis Typhon** »* de Scarron, un écrivain de la première moitié du XVII<sup>e</sup>, n’aide pas vraiment à convaincre que cette structure grammaticale soit simplement rare plutôt qu’entièrement disparue. Quant au *« Je, sousigné »* des administations (ainsi que les  *« Je Montée de lait jure solennellement que »* des serments devant la justice), c’est du jargon légal, qui a une indéniable valeur, mais qui vise principalement non à la beauté ou à l’élégance, mais à couper court à toute ambiguïté ou volonté d’interprétation.

Il y a aussi eu, quelques siècles avant Scarron, un certain poète dont nous ouïmes dire qu’il eut une influence non-négligeable sur des écrivains de différentes époques, dont Rabelais au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle et les romantiques au XIX<sup>e</sup>, pour en mentionner quelques-uns du temps d’avant Claudel. Ce poète produisit un *« **Je, François Villon escollier** »* au deuxième vers de son [*Lais*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6468587z/f35.image.r=%22Je%20Francois%20villon%22). Il n’y avait pas que Scarron que l’on pouvait citer, et bien que la langue de Villon soit un peu datée, elle demeure somme toute pas si éloignée du français moderne. Aujourd’hui, maintenant que l’écrivain Jean Teule a produit un roman historique intitulé [*Je, François Villon*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je,_Fran%C3%A7ois_Villon), superbement adapté en bande dessinée par [Luigi Critone](https://www.babelio.com/livres/Critone-Je-Francois-Villon-Tome-1--Mais-ou-sont-les-neige/312466), il semble que cet exemple serait probablement plus parlant que celui de Scarron, et la relative visibilité du roman a peut-être rendu la tournure plus facile d’approche qu’au temps de Claudel. Mais c’est spéculatif.

Était-ce vraiment incompréhensible, cependant ? C’est très douteux. Si la position qu’occupe ***je*** dans la traduction de Claudel est loin d’être habituelle, le mot lui-même est encore très vivant en français, et le restera longtemps après notre disparition à tous ici.

Était-elle inélégante ? C’est une question d’opinion difficile à trancher. Je, si j’ose commencer (et terminer...) mon enquête par moi-même, l’aime plutôt. Mais je, conscient de la particularité des opinions individuelles, me garderai de conclure que mon appréciation des phrasés exotiques est partagée par le plus grand nombre. Et j’admettrais que l’on ait pu juger que la tournure allait à l’encontre d’une certaine idée générale de ce que peut ou doit être le style français.

Par contre, être prêt à admettre ne veut pas dire être convaincu qu’il s’agit là du fond du problème. Je me permets donc d’étudier quelques autres pistes de réflexion.

Quant à une traduction archaïsante, je laisse l’hypothèse de côté. Patmore était un homme du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle et il n’était nul besoin de vieillir artificiellement son texte. Les reliques d’autres époques pouvaient être mises à profit, ce ***Je*** suspendu le démontre suffisamment, mais seulement si elles permettaient de rendre le texte plus fidèlement.

Voyons donc ce que Claudel aurait pu, en traducteur sourcier, inclure dans sa traduction.

---

#### Des majuscules

Jean de La Fontaine, au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, publiait plusieurs recueils de fables qui allaient tous connaître un fabuleux retentissement. On y lit dans son premier recueil (édition de [1688](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57600b/f41.image)) :

> #### La Cigale & la Fourmy
>
> La Cigale ayant chanté
>   Tout l’Esté,
>   Se trouva for dépourveuë
>   Quand la Bize fut venuë.
>   Pas un seul petit morceau
>   De mouche ou de vermisseau.
>   Elle alla crier famine
>   Chez la Fourmy sa voisine,
>   La priant de luy préter
>   Quelque grain pour subsister
>   Jusqu’à la saison nouvelle.

On prêtera ici attention au fait que les acteurs principaux, la Cigale et la Fourmi, mais aussi des êtres aussi abstraits que l’Été ou la Bise, reçoivent une majuscule. La Fontaine s’est pourtant bien gardé de donner cette majuscule à la mouche ou au vermisseau, simples fournisseurs de potentiels petits morceaux de nourriture. Il y a là une certaine logique, que le français moderne ne se soucie pas toujours de contempler ou apprécier (voir par exemple [ceci](https://www.poetica.fr/poeme-205/jean-de-la-fontaine-cigale-fourmi/), où ni la bise, ni l'été ne sont considérés comme dignes d’une entorse à la grammaire moderne habituelle).

Patmore, dans son poème, accorde le privilège de la majuscule aux Saisons en tant que groupe, à l’Hiver nommé(e) en particulier dès le quatrième vers, ainsi qu’aux autres saisons nommées plus loin et à quelques autres entités (le rouge-gorge et le temps des amours). Claudel **s’est à peu près gardé d’inclure ces particularités** dans sa traduction, ne conservant curieusement de toutes celles mentionnée que celle de la première instance de *Printemps*, et la délaissant même pour sa seconde apparition.

---

#### Un changement de genre

On trouve ici et là des sources qui indiquent que Rimbaud aurait utilisé *« **cet atmosphère personnel** »* dans *Soir historique*, par exemple [ici](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/etudlitt/2011-v42-n1-etudlitt5005183/1007156ar.pdf) en page 4, ou [ici](https://books.google.ca/books?id=G3gksXEocwsC&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=%22cet+atmosph%C3%A8re+personnel%22&source=bl&ots=hkaohjoozn&sig=wu15xyg0p19y0JgcGESl62DNlQc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_zu74tcDfAhXLk1kKHRvyBSkQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22cet%20atmosph%C3%A8re%20personnel%22&f=false) dans une édition bilingue, tournure que l’on ne retrouve cependant pas dans l’édition de [1886](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b8610832j/f107.image) des *Illuminations*.

La poésie peut, dans une certaine mesure et avec modération, se permettre ce genre de licence.

Et le fait est que l’Hiver est féminine dans l’original anglais, langue pourtant parcimonieuse dans ses attributions de genre.

Cette féminité avait-elle une valeur, offrait-elle une image au lecteur anglais que la masculinité du terme français, non explicitée mais vraisemblablement ressentie par défaut par le lectorat francophone, annulerait ?

Je pencherais pour la positive, surtout que ce silence sur le genre de l’Hiver s’ajoute au fait que cette dernière ne fût pas même personnifiée en français (*h* minuscule).

---

#### Répétition de *love* au second vers

On a noté en commentaire sous la question que *chérir* n’est pas *to love*. C’est un point de vue défendable. Mais que faire de ce trio *love / lovely / beloved* du second vers de l’original ? Le goût français ne prise pas outre mesure la répétition. Claudel n’a pas désiré ou pas osé lui imposer un semblable groupe dans sa traduction. Aurait-il dû ou pu être plus audacieux ? Il est vrai que *aimer / aimable / aimé* n’aurait pas tout à fait rendu justice au vers de Patmore.

Puisque nous avons *not beloved* en anglais, Claudel aurait pu se rabattre sur un  non-conventionnel *(à cette époque du moins)* ***mal-aimé***, utilisé quelques années auparavant par Apollinaire dans sa [*Chanson du mal-aimé*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Chanson_du_mal-aim%C3%A9) (publié au *Mercure de France*, cependant... peut-être qu’une malsaine compétition existait alors entre ce dernier et la NRF ?). C’est une option parmi d’autres. Mais le rôle du traducteur, tel que je le perçois du moins, se doit d’inclure ce genre de recherches sur la langue, afin de servir au mieux l’auteur traduit.

---

#### En conclusion

À la lumière de ce qui précède, on peut légitimement se demander si la traduction avait des ambitions sourcières si marquées.

Et en vertu de ce constat, on pourra à juste titre affirmer que ce ***Je*** suspendu en faisait trop ou trop peu. Trop car le reste de la traduction reste dans les balises naturelles du français du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle (et un simple ***Moi*** eût assez convenablement rempli la fonction du ***I*** anglais), ou trop peu quand on constate toutes les autres subtilités du poème original délaissées dans la traduction.

---

#### Une opinion de Claudel sur le style d’un poète

À propos d’une autre critique, dirigée contre l’*Otage* auquel on reprochait une syntaxe barbare et un sujet absurde, Claudel commenta :

> Pense-t-il vraiment qu’il me faut imiter les vers de Molière, de Ronsard, de Voltaire ou d’Alfred de Musset, qui sont pour moi la platitude même plutôt que de livrer ma propre respiration, celle de mon imagination, l’expression de mon idéal, de mon besoin absolu ? Le poète est fait pour apporter un enrichissement, des éléments nouveaux ! Il n’a pas à obéir, ni à subir, mais à créer...

Comment: Un grand merci pour cette étude remarquable. Une observation toute personnelle rel (*frémir la critique / plutôt Scarron que Villon*). Nous sommes ici en plein dans la partie polémique de l'histoire de la NRF. En pleine bagarre NRF/AF/Les Guêpes et quibusdam allis. Pas de critique qui frémit mais bien des *assassinats à coup de langues* (chers à Scarron). Provo / Réponse à provo / Vraies-Fausses louanges / critiques fictives / écrivains fictifs...

Comment: Bref... tout ce pataquès mal digéré, je ne peux plus tenir ce *je* isolé pour autre chose que scarronesque donc... c'est bien à dire encore... sarcastiquement provocateur. Et... ça a marché! ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt Scarron et non Villon appartient à l'Histoire, c'est avéré. Scarron EST l'exemple choisi/fourni par Claudel. Mon opinion ou ma perception n'ont ici rien à voir. Je disais simplement qu'aujourd'hui, on aurait peut-être choisi Villon, car son utilisation d'un ***Je*** isolé est désormais plus présente, sans doute plus connue.

Comment: Je crois qu'aujourd'hui, qui connaît l'un connaît l'autre alors... aujourd'hui... le driver du choix (pour moi) est le besoin de polémiquer. D'une fine référence polémique en tiroir. Pour mon testament... je choisirai l'autre évidemment... ;-) Bon allez... vous me direz... de nos jours... la polémique ne s'encombre plus de finesses... résolvant le problème du choix en un ni l'un ni l'autre. Las!

Comment: @aCOSwt J'ai réfléchi un peu, et je crois pour l'instant que je m'en tiendrai à un frémissement de la critique. Ça a provoqué des réactions, et les réponses ne furent pas élogieuses. Mais s'il n'y avait rien que de déjà jugé, on se serait sans doute simplement garder de commenter. On a peut-être regretté ne pas être celui qui osa. On a peut-être voulu très fort ne pas reconnaître qu'il y avait là de la valeur. On a peut-être simplement été submergé de colère à l'idée d'un tel affront au bon goût. Mais on a frémi.

Comment: @aCOSwt Et pour la petite histoire, je fus longtemps avisé de l'utilisation de Villon, et seulement récemment, à la lecture de cette question, au courant de celle de Scarron (ou de celle de Claudel). J'ai lu le *Lais* de Villon plusieurs fois, mais demeure toujours étranger au *Virgile travesti* de Scarron, dont je ne connais que les quelques premiers vers, lus en préparant cette réponse.

Comment: Je, sans hésiter, plussoie !

Answer (score 3):

Aujourd'hui, *je* doit être collé au verbe, pour être compréhensible (éventuellement séparé par quelque pronom COD ou COI) => *j'aime l'hiver, singulièrement ...*

La séparation ne se fait plus. Les 2 exemples donnés sont une bonne comparaison car il utilise aussi ce style incongru de nos jours.

En forme compréhensible d'aujourd'hui, on pourrait dire:

> Moi, qui suis singulièrement animé à chérir ce qui, aimable, n'est
>   pas aimé, entre toutes saisons le plus, j'aime l'hiver, et poursuivre
>   ce sens de la pâleur Trophonienne sur sa face. [...]

Comment: Je suis d'accord. Mais c'est Moi, et pas Mois. :) Le je qui d'antan serait Moi qui de nos jours....

Comment: @Lambie - merci - corrigé !

Comment: Puisqu'on en est aux corrections :  « singulièrement... » pas « singulièrement ....», « collé au verbe pour être compréhensible», pas « collé au verbe, pour être compréhensible », « compréhensible aujourd'hui » plutôt que « compréhensible d'aujourd'hui », « Les deux exemples », pas « Les 2 exemples » et « qui suis », pas « qui suit ». Je mettrais aussi probablement le « je » utilisé comme substantif entre guillemets pour que le « je doit » ne choque pas.

Comment: Merci ! Pouvez-vous peut-être approfondir un peu si vous en avez l'occasion. Par exemple, vous avez opté pour le pronom disjoint _moi_ dans votre rendu, et avez effectué une reprise du pronom _j'aime_ et introduit une virgule qui est absente autant de l'original que de sa traduction. Pouvez-vous vous prononcer à savoir si vous considérez que _je,...,aime_ est équivalent à _moi,..., j'aime_ en termes de registre. Je spécule à l'effet que la langue de Patmore est soutenue et moi+je l'est-il ? Deuxièmement, pouvez-vous svp vous prononcer sur la reprise du pronom (avec ou sans). Merci.